# Using Cusor for next and previous nevigation in Apache Solr

Tags: php, apache, solr, pagination

I have been trying to use `Cursors`([document](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Pagination+of+Results)) to make a "Next" and "Previous" pagination. I find it strange that there is no such thing as `prevCursorMark` as opposed to `nextCursorMark` in the returned data. It makes implementing next and prev pagination quite difficult.

I came up with the idea of storing the previous `nextCursorMark` request as the previous page pointer. However I felt that it wouldn't be as reliable as simply having a `prevCursorMark`.

Example Code with PHP Solr Extension

```
  $query_response = $client->query($solrQuery);

  $data = $query_response->getResponse();

  $nextCursorMark = $data['nextCursorMark'];

  $prevCursorMark = isset($_GET['nextResult'])?
                    htmlspecialchars($_GET['nextResult']):'*';


  $pager = "<a href='index?1=1&nextResult=$prevCursorMark' class='page5 no_ajax'>Prev</a>
            <a href='index?1=1&nextResult=$nextCursorMark' class='page5 no_ajax'>Next</a>";
```

So here's my question: Does `Cursors` in `Solr` provide a prevCursor Mark? Is it possible to make a next and previous pagination with `Cursors`?

Answer (score 1):

As of the solr 5.2, it does not provide any `previous cursor mark`. If you want to provide the pagination in your application with next and previous links. You can reliably store and use `nextCursorMark` values returned by the solr. You can re-submit `nextCursorMark` values, changing other things like what stored fields are returned or what fields are faceted. The cursorMark parameter itself contains all the necessary state. There is no server-side state.